# Need to get the string which is in single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the string like `how are you 'xyz', bye`.

Here I need to take out the `xyz` alone, which is in single quotes in the above string. I can use a SQL query or stored procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there always exactly one occurance of a substring in single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this

```
declare @x  varchar(50)= 'how are you ''xyz'', bye'
select substring(left(@x,charindex(',',@X)-2),charindex('''',@x)+1,len(@x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions (*regex*).  This will work: `\'xyz\'`.  Or use this for any # of characters: `\'.*\'`

Answer (score 0):

I have in my database for this special function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_GetTextFromQuotes (@text nvarchar(max), @IsDoubleQuotes bit = 0)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @Pos int, @EndPos int, @string nvarchar(max), @Quotes nvarchar(max)

  IF @IsDoubleQuotes = 1 
    SET @Quotes = '"'
  ELSE
    SET @Quotes = ''''

  SET @string = ''
  SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Quotes, @text, 0)

  WHILE @Pos != 0
  BEGIN
      SET @EndPos = CHARINDEX(@Quotes, @text, @Pos + 1 )
      IF @string != '' 
        SET @string = @string + ','
      SET @string = @string +SUBSTRING(@text, @Pos + 1 ,  @EndPos - @Pos - 1)

      SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Quotes, @text, @EndPos + 1 )
  END
  RETURN @string
END
```

And use:

```
select dbo.ufn_GetTextFromqQuotes('how are you ''xyz'', bye', default ) as result
```

Comment: Wow that is a complicated way to get there. The performance of this is going to be pretty painful for many datasets.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But it  was long ago someone created and we still use it ((

Comment: Just because it has been around for a long time doesn't mean it is good. This would be so simple to rewrite into an inline table valued function. Not only would it be way simpler it would be faster.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I have time I'll rewrite it